# How to use where and filter in GraphQL in one query?

Tags: graphql

It is possible using in one query also where and filter.
At the moment it is my query:

```
  query Memories($id: ID!) {
      memories(where: { event: { id: $id } }) {
        id
        name
        story
      }
    }
```

I want add filter:

```
filter: {
    name: {
      anyofterms: "england"
    },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the schema of your API, as there is no "general" filter concept in GraphQL. The API must explicity define such a feature.
If your API defines a filter on the `memories` field, than you could probably specify both `filter` *and* `where`, like so:

```
query Memories($id: ID!) {
      memories(
        where: { event: { id: $id } },
        filter: { name: { anyofterms: "england" } }
      ) {
        id
        name
        story
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nils, I have one questions:
Hello

I'm newbie, I using graphql in my store on next.js.
At the moment I created all queries, and mutations by trial and error method.

Which sources is good for me, for discover all popular query scheme etc for graphic?

At the moment I am using sources like:

https://hygraph.com/docs/api-reference/content-api/filtering

https://buildkite.com/docs/apis/graphql/graphql-cookbook

Maybe another source is better, I want to know all options in build queries, etc.